# Inverse of $y = Ax^3 + Bx + C$

Tags: polynomials, inverse-function

I know there already is a question and a bunch of excellent answers in [How to find the inverse of $y=x^3-5x^2+3x+c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233404/how-to-find-the-inverse-of-y-x3-5x23xc).

But here I am having a more general (and thus complicated) form to invert. I am stuck in obtaining the inverse, $g^{-1}$, of a polynomial
\begin{align}
y = g\left(x\right) = -\frac{x^3}{8r} - r\left(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)x + 2\sqrt{2}r^2, {\rm{~~~~}} 0 \le x \le \sqrt{2}r
\end{align}
where $r > 0$ is a constant and a real number.

The function $g$ is certainly invertible as being strictly decreasing when drawn:
[image]

**Question:**

(1) I would like to ask you guys if there would be a way to find a **closed-form** expression for $x = g^{-1}\left(y\right)$.

(2) Also, any **approximation of $y$** for making it easier to be inverted will be most welcome as well.

Thanks a lot guys. I love you all!

Comment: The closed form is the "cubic formula" ... but that is so complicated that it will likely be of no use to you.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html

Comment: You might be interested in learning some basic Galois theory. It'll make your understanding of how the roots of polynomials over a field behave, which is crucial in finding inverses.

Answer (score 3):

Consider that you need to solve for $x$ the cubic equation
$$ -\frac{x^3}{8r} - r\left(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)x + \left(2\sqrt{2}r^2-y\right)=0$$
Applying the method for [cubic equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function), you would find
$$\Delta=-\frac{27 \left(2 \sqrt{2} r^2-y\right)^2}{64 r^2}-\frac{1}{2}
   \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^3 r^2$$ and, since $\Delta <0$, then only one real root. On the other hand $$ p=8 \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) r^2\qquad \text{and}\qquad q=-8 r \left(2 \sqrt{2} r^2-y\right)$$

Using [the hyperbolic solution for one real root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Hyperbolic_solution_for_one_real_root)

$$x=4 \sqrt{\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{3} }  \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{3\sqrt{3} \left(2 \sqrt{2} r^2- y\right)}{2
   \left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)^{3/2} r^2}\right)\right)\,r$$

**Edit**

It would have been simpler to let $x= X r \sqrt 2$ and $y= 2Y {r^2}\sqrt 2$ which make the equation to be dimensionless and rescaled
$$\sqrt{2} X^3+4 \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right) X-8 \sqrt{2} (1-Y)=0$$
the solution of which being
$$X=2 \sqrt{\frac{2\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)}{3} } \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{3 \sqrt{6} }{\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)^{3/2}}(1-Y)\right)\right)$$

Comment: (+1) for demonstrating a non-algebraic approach, which is often better suited for studying analytic properties and obtaining numerical values.