# Find inverse of a function $f(x)=x^3+3x^2+4x-1$

Tags: calculus, functions, inverse-function

If $f(x)=x^3+3x^2+4x-1$,  then $f(x)$ is one to one as it is increasing function for $x \in R$. I want to find $x$ such that

> $\frac{-1}{4}x-\frac{7}{16}=2f^{-1}(\frac{-x}{2}-1)$

**my attempt:**

One option is that calculate $f^{-1}$ , inverse of $f$, and then changes $x$ to $\frac{-x}{2}-1$  in $f^{-1}$ and then solve the equation.

I don't know how to find inverse here

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: To invert your function one would need to apply the general cubic equation, and another thing to worry about is that cubic polys are not one-to-one so techniclly no inverse exists. Maybe for what you need you can get by with an inverse on a restricted domain of the cubic.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233404/how-to-find-the-inverse-of-y-x3-5x23xc) answer your question?

Comment: or $ f(\frac{-x}{8}-\frac{7}{32})=\frac{-x}{2}-1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing that an inverse exists tells us that the equation $\frac{-x}{4} - \frac{7}{16} = 2 f^{-1}\bigl(\frac{-x}{2} - 1\bigr)$ is equivalent to

$$
f\Bigl(\frac{-x}{8} - \frac{7}{32}\Bigr) = \frac{-x}{2} - 1.
$$

Or $f(y) = 4 y - \frac{1}{8}$, where $y = \frac{-x}{8} - \frac{7}{32}$, which can be rewritten as

$$\begin{align}
y^3 + 3 y^2 - 7/8 &= 0 \\
8y^3 + 24y^2 - 7 &= 0.
\end{align}$$

We can avoid using the cubic formula by testing, according to the rational root theorem, the numbers $\pm 1, \pm \frac{1}{2}, \pm \frac{1}{4}, \pm \frac{1}{8}, \pm 7, \pm \frac{7}{2}, \pm \frac{7}{4}, \pm \frac{7}{8}$. This gives $y = 1/2$ as a rational root, and dividing by $y - 1/2$ and using the quadratic formula gives the remaining two roots, $-7/4 \pm \sqrt{21}/4$.

Using the formula $x = -8y - 7/4$ on these three numbers gives the three solutions to our original equation

$$
x = -\frac{23}{4}, \frac{49}{4} \pm 2\sqrt{21}.
$$

Comment: shoteyes, thanks your answer, why you just accept $y=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @user62498 To save some time, going down the list of the possible rational roots, we see that plugging in $y = 1/2$ satisfies $8 y^3 + 24 y^2 - 7 = 0$. Once we have one root, we can divide our polynomial to get a quadratic one, and we don’t need to test anymore. Just use quadratic formula once we’re there.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Since the range of $f$ is $\Bbb{R}$, it is equivalent to solve
$$\frac{1}{2}f(t) + \frac{1}{16} = 2t$$

Then the desired $x$ is given by $x=-2(f(t)+1)$

Comment: Ninad Munshi, thank please explain a bit more here  $\frac{1}{2}f(t) + \frac{1}{16} = 2t$

Comment: @user62498 $x=-2(f(t)+1)$