# If $4^x + 4^{-x} = 5$, what is $8^x + 8^{-x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I found this competition math problem that I haven't been able to solve.

> If $4^x + 4^{-x} = 5$, find $8^x + 8^{-x}$.

Setting $a = 4^x$, we see the problem is equivalent to saying:

> If $a + a^{-1} = 5$, find $a^{3/2} + a^{-3/2}$.

So $a$ is the solution to the quadratic equation $a^2 - 5a+ 1 = 0$.  Explicitly, $a = \frac{5 + \sqrt{21}}{2}$, which is a unit in the ring integers of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{21})$.  The expression $a+a^{-1}$ is then equal to the trace of $a$.  Then $a^{3/2} + a^{-3/2}$ should be another trace.

I would love to see if there is a nice solution to this problem using algebraic number theory.  But it should also be possible to solve using elementary methods, since it is a high school competition math problem.

Comment: $~y^2 + \dfrac{1}{y^2} = \left(y + \dfrac{1}{y}\right)^2 - 2,~$ which implies that (without solving for $~2^x),~$ you can infer the value of $~\displaystyle \left(2^x + 2^{-x}\right).~$  From this, you can infer the value of $\displaystyle 2^{3x} + 2^{-3x} = \left(2^x + 2^{-x}\right)^3 - 3\left(2^x + 2^{-x}\right).$  The point of the question is that it is unnecessary to solve for either $~4^x~$ or $~2^x.$

Comment: Hint: use symmetric polynomial identities as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/16337/242) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1901150/242) (this is implicitly done in the answers below).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With $a=2^x$ we have $a^2+a^{-2}=5$ which means $a+\frac 1a=\sqrt 7$ or $a-\frac 1a=\sqrt 3$.  Then $a^3+a^{-3}=4\sqrt 7$.

Comment: Where does the fact that $a + \frac{1}{a} = \sqrt{7}$ or $a - \frac{1}{a} = \sqrt{3}$ come from?

Comment: To @Bryce: $(a + \tfrac{1}{a})^2 = a^2 + 2 + \frac{1}{a^2}$

Comment: @Bryce: use $a^2\pm 2+a^{-2}=(a\pm \frac 1a)^2$.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, very simple

Answer (score 6):

A trigonometric solution.  Note
$$
4^x+4^{-x} = e^{x\ln 4}+e^{-x\ln 4} = 2 \cosh(x\ln 4) = 2 \cosh(2x\ln 2),
$$
and similarly
$$
8^x+8^{-x} = 2 \cosh(3x\log 2)
$$
Writing $t=x\log 2$ we have
$$
4^x+4^{-x} = 2\cosh(2t) = 4\cosh^2(t)-2
\\
8^x+8^{-x} = 2\cosh(3t) = 8\cosh^3(t)-6\cosh(t)
$$
Now we are given $4^x+4^{-x} = 5$, so
$$
5=4\cosh^2(t)-2
\\
\frac{7}{4}=\cosh^2(t)
\\
\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2} = \cosh(t)
$$
where we assumed $x$ is real so that $\cosh(t) > 0$.
Finally,
$$
8^x+8^{-x} = 8\cosh^3(t)-6\cosh(t) =
 8\left(\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)^3 - 6\left(\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)
=4\sqrt{7} .
$$

Answer (score 2):

$(2^x+2^{-x})^2=4^x+4^{-x}+2=7$

$\therefore 8^x+8^{-x}=(2^x+2^{-x})^3-3(2^x+2^{-x})=4\sqrt7$